# JavaFX MousedMoved event ignored when mouse button is held down

Tags: java, javafx

The event within

```
main.getScene().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {}
```

is not called when the mouse button is held down, is there anyway around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mouse moved with the mouse button down is a `MOUSE_DRAGGED` event. So you can do:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = event -> { /* ... */};
main.getScene().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, handler);
main.getScene().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this move event when the mouse is pressed :

```
MOUSE_DRAGGED
```